# Why is a nested function so much slower than the unnested version?

Tags: python, performance, testing

I'm trying to contain memo dict inside fibonacci as I'm trying to pickle the function. However, in my tests, it seems that the nested function is significantly slower, but I don't see this with other versions of fibonacci only when I'm using the memoized function.

All my tests: https://gist.github.com/dasickis/4733353

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

memo = {0: 0, 1: 1}

# Contract: [int > 0] -> [int > 0]
def fibonacci(n):
    """ Return the `x`th number in the fibonacci series. """
    if not n in memo:
        memo[n] = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
    return memo[n]

#--------------------------#

# Contract: [int > 0] -> [int > 0]
def fibonacci_nested(n):
    memo = {0: 0, 1: 1}

    def fib(n):
        """ Return the `x`th number in the fibonacci series. """
        if not n in memo:
            memo[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
        return memo[n]

    return fib(n)

#--------------------------#

import timeit
stmt = "assert fib(20) == 6765"

print "fibonacci"
print timeit.timeit(stmt, setup="from __main__ import fibonacci as fib")
print 

print "fibonacci_nested"
print timeit.timeit(stmt, setup="from __main__ import fibonacci_nested as fib")
```

Outputs:

```
fibonacci
0.263559103012

fibonacci_nested
11.4014730453
```

Comment: I hope you read carefully the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) about how functions and classes are "pickled". "Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully qualified” name reference, not by value. This means that only the function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the function is defined in. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its function attributes are pickled. Thus the defining module must be importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain the named object"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't clean the `memo` dictionary between runs giving the version without nesting an unfair advantage. The first time `timeit` runs `fib` it'll fill the `memo` dict and then subsequent runs re-use it.

The nested function sets up a new, empty `memo` each time.